# Display price on Views for product variation

Tags: views, commerce

I'm confused, how to display on Views just one price for product with variations? I have product with 2 variation, and both prices are displayed, like:
Price: 1-Price for 1-Variation-Product , Price: 2-Price for 2-Variation-Product

I mean the created from me some custom view-page, like "/all-products" (like some catalog page) where are displayed all of products or goods with their prices. And for the products with variations I see, that there will be displayed all of prices of this product.

In the Settings of View-Page ("/all-products") I have in **Format section**: "*Show:Fields | Settings*".

In **RELATIONSHIPS**:
*Variations: Product variation*

*(Variations: Product variation) Product: Product*

And in **Fields** I have:
*(Variations: Product variation) Product variation relationship: Price*

where in the Setting I have:
"*Use entity field rendering*"

There are no Setting to handle multiple values.

If I check out "*Use entity field rendering*" then will be shown some settings for handling of multiple values, but in this case it will be no price displayed on view-page (/all-products), because the prices are rendering from product entity, as I understand.

So, this is the problem

In addition: the product with variation has all the same price, not different prices for different variation.

What is teh best way to handle it?

I have **Drupal 9**, **Commerce 2**

Thanks

Comment: Very keep on achieving this this too. Did you work it out? My use case is a views page for a search api / facets-based product catalog. My add to cart is using the Variation Title widget.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution, in "**Fields**" just instead

"*(Variations: Product variation) Product variation relationship: Price*"

need to use:

"*Product datasource: Variations*", and there are some settings to handle multiple values.

In "**Formatter**" need to set "*Rendered entry*", instead default "*Label*"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your view is configured, but here is a basic setup that will only show one price.

Create a view of **Products** with the **Default** view mode.

Then configure the **Default** view mode at `/admin/commerce/config/product-types/MY_PRODUCT_TYPE/edit/display`.

For **Variations**, you can change the **Format** to **Add to cart form**, which will show a dropdown for selecting the variations and the price of the current variation only.  You can check out the other options too; one of them may be better for your use case.

Comment: thanks for answering, but this settings I have already and on Product page I have dropdown for selecting the variations. With my question "Display price on Views " I mean the created from me some custom view-page, like "/all-products" (like some catalog page) where are displayed all of products  or goods with theyr prices. And for the products with variations I see, that there will be displayed all of prices of this product.

Comment: @lexx You need to describe exactly how you created your custom view page; what is displayed is controlled based on the settings, so without you sharing the exact settings, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: @lexx You should edit your question to include this information instead of posting it in a comment; that way, people who visit this question page will find all the information in the question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I changed the question and delete my comments from above